# How can I solve typemismatch in Spark 1.2.0 with same type of found and required object?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have implemented the following case class and a function to transform each row of a org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD in this case class:

```
case class FeatureVector(c: String, s: String, a: String, r: String, ra: String, d: String)

val raw_features = res.map( row => {
    val Seq(c,s,a,p,ra,d) = row.map(_.toString)

    new FeatureVector(c, s, a, map_prov_to_reg(p), ra, d)
})
```

When I try to apply a function, that takes as argument a FeatureVector, to raw_features.first (that would be a FeatureVector) I have this error:

```
<console>:58: error: type mismatch;

 found   : FeatureVector(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)

 required: FeatureVector(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)(in class $iwC)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a known issue that can occur when defining case classes within a Spark shell:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5149